# What should I do to maintains the background change for all session, until the user wants to change?

Tags: session, background, session-variables

I try to open a session that changes the background style. However, to link button to background, I use Javascript and add a class by calling a function when I click, as right here:
[Trying to change  classes with PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4c5UE.png)
[Trying to add $_SESSION in PHP in a JS condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYokG.png)
[Light background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqWhV.jpg)
[Dark background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZBuX.jpg)

Then, I check if my variable $_SESSION['background'] worth "dark" or "white" but it does always worth "dark", as I could see by writing it down with an echo in PHP. So if I update the page on my browser, the background is always dark. Where's my mistake? What should I do? Thank you a lot